# How to define optional protocol requirements in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

As far as I know you need to annotate a function this way:

```
@objc MyProtocol{
optional func yourOptionalMethod()
}
```

But why is it needed the @objc annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267):

> NOTE
>
> Optional protocol requirements can only be specified if your protocol
>   is marked with the @objc attribute.
>
> This attribute indicates that the protocol should be exposed to
>   Objective-C code and is described in Using Swift with Cocoa and
>   Objective-C. Even if you are not interoperating with Objective-C, you
>   need to mark your protocols with the @objc attribute if you want to
>   specify optional requirements.
>
> Note also that @objc protocols can be adopted only by classes, and not
>   by structures or enumerations. If you mark your protocol as @objc in
>   order to specify optional requirements, you will only be able to apply
>   that protocol to class types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have posed this question after reading this piece of documentation. I don't find a real explanation there.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267):

Also,

> Optional protocol requirements can only be specified if your protocol is >marked with the @objc attribute.
>
> This attribute indicates that the protocol should be exposed to >Objective-C code and is described in Using Swift with Cocoa and >Objective-C. Even if you are not interoperating with Objective-C, you >need to mark your protocols with the @objc attribute if you want to >specify optional requirements.
>
> Note also that @objc protocols can be adopted only by classes, and not >by structures or enumerations. If you mark your protocol as @objc in >order to specify optional requirements, you will only be able to apply >that protocol to class types.

Again, explained here in Swift Documentation:

```
/// The protocol to which all types implicitly conform
typealias Any = protocol


/// The protocol to which all class types implicitly conform.
///
/// When used as a concrete type, all known `@objc` `class` methods and
/// properties are available, as implicitly-unwrapped-optional methods
/// and properties respectively, on each instance of `AnyClass`. For
/// example:
///
/// .. parsed-literal:
///
///   class C {
///     @objc class var cValue: Int { return 42 }
///   }
///
///   // If x has an @objc cValue: Int, return its value.  
///   // Otherwise, return nil.
///   func getCValue(x: AnyClass) -> Int? {
///     return **x.cValue**
///   }
///
/// See also: `AnyObject`
typealias AnyClass = AnyObject.Type


/// The protocol to which all classes implicitly conform.
///
/// When used as a concrete type, all known `@objc` methods and
/// properties are available, as implicitly-unwrapped-optional methods
/// and properties respectively, on each instance of `AnyObject`.  For
/// example:
///
/// .. parsed-literal:
///
///   class C {
///     @objc func getCValue() -> Int { return 42 }
///   }
///
///   // If x has a method @objc getValue()->Int, call it and
///   // return the result.  Otherwise, return nil.
///   func getCValue1(x: AnyObject) -> Int? {
///     if let f: ()->Int = **x.getCValue** {
///       return f()
///     }
///     return nil
///   }
///
///   // A more idiomatic implementation using "optional chaining"
///   func getCValue2(x: AnyObject) -> Int? {
///     return **x.getCValue?()**
///   }
///
///   // An implementation that assumes the required method is present
///   func getCValue3(x: AnyObject) -> **Int** {
///     return **x.getCValue()** // x.getCValue is implicitly unwrapped.
///   }
///
/// See also: `AnyClass`
@objc protocol AnyObject {
}
```