# Optional Variables in protocol is possible?

Tags: swift, protocols

```
protocol AProtocol: BProtocol {
    /// content to be shown on disclaimer Label of cell
    var disclaimer: String {get set}
    var cellDisclaimerAttributed: NSAttributedString {get}
    var showSelection: Bool {get set}
    var isReadMore: Bool {get}
}
```

**I want to make variables optional so that I need not implement all variables every time after conforming protocol. Like  in Objective-C we did for methods:**

```
protocol AProtocol: BProtocol {
    /// content to be shown on disclaimer Label of cell
    optional var disclaimer: String {get set}
    optional var cellDisclaimerAttributed: NSAttributedString {get}
    optional var showSelection: Bool {get set}
    optional var isReadMore: Bool {get}
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: The error message for the second example you give says *"'optional' can only be applied to members of an @objc protocol"* (hint hint)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478562/optional-protocol-requirements-i-cant-get-it-to-work, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333863/how-to-define-optional-protocol-requirements-in-swift ?

Comment: Above links are talking about methods only.  @MartinR

Comment: @Ren: Does it make a difference?

Comment: No after adding @objc to protocols, still throwing an error to implement all variables in that class.

Comment: @Martin yes for methods, it is working, but not for variables.

Comment: @Ren: Are you sure? I just tried `@objc protocol MyProtocol { @objc optional var disclaimer: String { get set } }` and `class Foo: MyProtocol { }`.

Comment: Please conform this protocol to any other class, you will get the error.

Comment: @Ren: If AProtocol inherits from  BProtocol then of course *both* protocols (and the optional property) have to be marked with `@objc`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    var name : String {set get}
    var age : Int {set get}
}
```

Provide a default extension for the protocol. Provide the default implementation for all the variables set and get which u want them to be optional.

**In below protocol, name and age are optional.**

```
 extension TestProtocol {

    var name: String {
        get { return "Any default Name" } set {}
    }  
    var age : Int { get{ return 23 } set{} }      
}
```

Now if I am conforming above protocol to any other class, like

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController, TestProtocol{
        var itemName: String = ""

**I can implement the name only, and my objective is achieved here, that the controller will not give a warning that "TestViewController does not conform to protocol TestProtocol"**

   var name: String {
        get {
            return itemName ?? ""
        } set {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in `TestViewController` you don't need to implement the `get set`. Having the variable defined as `var itemName: String = ""` is all that's needed.

Comment: Be careful! In this solution, `name` and `age` is not changeable from instance, e.g: after setting `testVC.age = 30` `age` remains 23!

Answer (score 10):

If you want to [conform to Swift's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID284), you'd have to implement it like this :

```
@objc protocol Named {
    // variables
    var name: String { get }
    @objc optional var age: Int { get }
  
    // methods
    func addTen(to number: Int) -> Int
    @objc optional func addTwenty(to number: Int) -> Int
}

class Person: Named {
    var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    func addTen(to number: Int) -> Int {
        return number + 10
    }
}
```